# Требовалось по точкам узнать координаты векторов и их длину. Из-за чего в конце ошибка с типами?

Tags: c++, методы, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct Kor //коорд. точки
 {
  float x;  
  float y;
 };

struct Point
 {
  Kor p;   
 };   

 float length (Point * a) 
 {
  return sqrt( a->p.x*a->p.x  +  a->p.y*a->p.y ); 
 }

  float VecKor (Point *a, Point *b) //коорд вектора
  {
   return  (b->p.x - a->p.x); 
   return  (b->p.y - a->p.y); 
  }

 main()
{
 Point AB,BC,CA;
 Point A {2,3};
 Point B {7,5};
 Point C {7,3};

 AB=VecKor(*A,*B); //error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is'Point')

}
```

Comment: Вы вопрос забыли задать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Вы перепутали разыменование указателя (звёздочка * ) и взятие адреса (амперсанд &).

К тому же у вас есть ещё ошибки.

1) Попробуйте вашу строчку с ошибкой заменить на:

```
AB=VecKor(&A,&B);
```

2) В функции `float VecKor (Point *a, Point *b)` вы возвращаете зачем-то `float`, хотя по логике она должна возвращать точку, исправляем:

```
Point VecKor(Point *a, Point *b) //коорд вектора
{
    Kor rv1 = {b->p.x - a->p.x, b->p.y - a->p.y};
    Point rv = {rv1};
    return rv;
}
```

[Ваш исправленный код](http://cpp.sh/6wkbl).

Comment: Не получается( no match for 'operator = ' (operand types are 'Point' and 'float') ) и чего-то в Point появилась ошибка( no known conversion for argument 1 from 'float' to 'const Point&')

Comment: Это уже другая ошибка. Первую вы исправили. Сейчас добавлю по другим ответ.

Answer (score 1):

тип данных АВ:
  Point AB
тип данных VecKor:
float VecKor
Вы пытаетесь присвоить типу данных поинт тип данных флоат. Внимательнее с этим.

Comment: А можно в методе VecKor возвращаемый тип на Point сменить?

Comment: да, только тогда как-то так:
Point VecKor (Point *a, Point *b) //коорд вектора
  {
Point k {b->p.x - a->p.x, b->p.y - a->p.y}; 
return k;
  }
(простите, что в строку, еще не разобралась как делать кодом)

Comment: и когда вы один раз сделаете return  где-либо, во втором нету смысла, только если он не реализуется в части if-else

Comment: Спасибо огромное